# using {white-space:pre-wrap;overflow-wrap:break-word;} the SAME CONTENT broken ALL if I put into table, why?

Tags: css

you can see,
is EXACTLY the same paragraph:

https://jsfiddle.net/spwdn2mg/

but if I put `{...text...}` into `<td> </td>` then ALL is creazy.

how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Tables have a separate, complicated algorithm for calculating the widths of the cells, and this is an edge case. I experimented and

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

seems to fix the issue as you wished.